# Scala : print only during unit test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I want to display in the output window, but only during Unit tests and not during normal execution. I am using Scalatest for UT. Any idea how this can be handled in a clean way?

```
println("DataFrame results:")
dataFrame.show(100, false)
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at what's logging and how it can be configured differently according the various runtime or test environement.

Comment: If you want to display that only during Unit testing, then move the code in a Unit Test, but there is no point printing it in a Unit Test because you cannot assert the results of the DataFrame in the Console.  If you don't want it print during normal execution, then there is no point in having it there either. So a question to ask yourself is do you really need to print the results at this particular point ?

Comment: As said by @cchantep you should use a logging library and use a level like "debug" configured to be displayed in your tests but not in the production config.

Comment: How about `if (isUnitTest) dataFrame.show(100, false)` ?